# Excel-like conditional formatting with DataGrid: How to remove padding between cells

Tags: material-ui

I was trying to conditionally color a DataGrid based on its value similar to Excel. I rendered a Box inside each cell with width = 100% but there seems to have some 16px paddings on both left and right of each cell. Is there any way to remove such padding? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

function renderCell({value}) {
  const color = value > 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
  return <Box bgcolor={color} width={1}>{value}</Box>
}

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "Col"},
  { field: "A", headerName: "A", renderCell: (p) => renderCell(p)},
  { field: "B", headerName: "B", renderCell: (p) => renderCell(p)},
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, A: 100, B: -100},
  { id: 2, A: 50, B: 100}
];

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <DataGrid      
      autoHeight={true}
      columns={columns}
      rows={rows}
    />
  );
}
```